# UITableview with two data per row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

i want to have two data on each row on my tableview.
Something like Recent Call  (on the left the name, on the right the day)

this is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    //cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellStyleValue1 ;
}

// Configure the cell.

NSDictionary *dictionary = [listaOggetti objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Elementi"];
NSString *cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSArray *array1  = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Tipo"];
NSString *cellDetail = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if ([indexPath row] == 0){
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    cell.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
} else {

cell.textLabel.text = cellDetail;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = cellValue;
}

return cell;
}
```

i've try to use different style on

```
initWithStyle
```

without any result (only show my detailtext on the right).
In NSLOG i see the right value of cellDetail.

```
{
    Elementi =         (
        "Chiamate e Videochiamate Nazionali",
        "08m:43s",
        "1h:31m:17s",
        "1h:40m:00s"
    );
},
    {
    Tipo =         (
        Effettuato,
        Rimanente,
        Totale
    );
},
    {
    Elementi =         (
        "SMS e MMS Nazionali",
        21,
        29,
        50
    );
},
    {
    Tipo =         (
        Effettuato,
        Rimanente,
        Totale
    );
},
    {
    Elementi =         (
        "Traffico Dati FMM",
        "69.95 MB",
        "954.05 MB",
        "1024.00 MB"
    );
},
    {
    Tipo =         (
        Effettuato,
        Rimanente,
        Totale
    );
},
    {
    Elementi =         (
        Skype,
        "00m:00s",
        "3h:20m:00s",
        "3h:20m:00s"
    );
},
    {
    Tipo =         (
        Effettuato,
        Rimanente,
        Totale
    );
},
    {
    Elementi =         (
        "WWW3, Yahoo!, Google, eBay e altri servizi",
        "0.00 MB",
        "100.00 MB",
        "100.00 MB"
    );
},
    {
    Tipo =         (
        Effettuato,
        Rimanente,
        Totale
    );
}
)
```

my goal is to obtain cells like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider [creating a custom Cell](http://icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/), its easy to do and it really looks the ticket if done well.

Otherwise, Your code looks ok, check that your labels have been alloc'd (not nil).

On a side note, how many items do you have in your dataset? I only ask because if its only 1, you never set detailTextLabel.

Comment: Completely unnecessary: initialize the cell properly, and use `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`.

Comment: Thank's Jonathan, my code is ok, i've found my mistake creating my second array, now app works great!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to initialize the cell like this, you are using the incorrect style when initializing the cell

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle       
                           reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Comment: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns a pointer to a reusable cell or nil, and he checks for nil after it and allocs if appropriate

Comment: @Luke Mcneice I believe he is using the wrong style when initializing the cell

Comment: i've try all the CellStyle, the result is the same. i'm attaching in my questions nslog output of my array

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the tableView, and possibly compare it to what it should look like- it will help understand your problem

Comment: i've upload a shoot of what i want to obtain:D

Comment: Creating a custom cell would be ideal, (linked in my post) what does your cells currently look like

Comment: You want `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`, not `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's to all, my code is ok, the fault is on the second array.
Solved in this way:

```
    NSDictionary *dictionary1 = [listaDettaglioOggetti objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *array1  = [dictionary1 objectForKey:@"Tipo"];
NSString *cellDetail = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

The last question:

i would modify the first row on each section (modify font size, color, aligment).
I've think something like this:

```
    NSInteger sectionRows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];
    if (sectionRows == 0){
    cell.textLabel.text = cellDetail;
    cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    } else {
cell.textLabel.text = cellDetail;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = cellValue;
}
```

but this don't make the magic:D
Please let me know if it's better to open another topic or we can continue here.